# Can't revel save a session in WebSocket Controller?

Tags: websocket, revel

I want create a Goroutine for each user to send websocket data sequentially. So, I wrote a code as below.

```
func (c User) List(ws *websocket.Conn) revel.Result {
    disconnect := make(chan bool)
    if c.Session["connected"] != "true" {
        c.Session["connected"] = "true"
        go func() {
            for {
                select {
                case <-ticker.C:
                    if websocket.JSON.Send(ws, &map[string]interface{}{"hoge": "fuga"}) != nil {
                        c.Session["connected"] = "false"
                        disconnect <- true
                    }
                }
            }
        }()
    }
    <-disconnect
    return nil
}
```

However, the code makes goroutines for each access.

And I tried the code as below.

```
func (c App) WebSocket(ws *websocket.Conn) revel.Result {
    fmt.Println(c.Session)
    c.Session["connected"] = "true"
    return nil
}
```

https://gist.github.com/uzimith/0066e863a0809d4a91ec

Output is this.

```
map[]
map[]
```

Can't revel save a session in WebSocket Controller?

I think we need a Session.Save method, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

I understood.

Revel uses cookie to save Session data. These value are stored in the cookie of the key "REVEL_SESSION". So, revel uses http header Set-Cookie when it save Cookie. However, we use websocket protocol. Therefore, we can't save cookie.